# Jenkins plugin 'Role-Based Strategy'

Tags: jenkins, role-based

Using Jenkins plugin 'Role-Based Strategy', I need to have user having access ONLY to a project pipeline only.
I added the user under 'Item roles', but user gets error:
'User id' is missing the Overall/Read permission
I am also using ldap, and the user is in ldap, by passes credential page and get error above.
I don't want to grant user global roles (i want user to have only specific access to project).

Any help

Answer (score -1):

Jenkins doesn't actually work as a web app or something where you can have roles. They assume that Jenkins will be used by development teams that need access to everything in a project. You can configure users to have access to project or not, but you cannot configure users to have access to specific jobs or not, even pipelines. Jenkins is not created that way and cannot handle your scenario.

You can give that user access to the whole folder (project), or don't give access at all.